# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Slate.exe

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm working on an application in C# and unexpectedly I started getting this exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Slate.exe".

Following are the details of my code.

This is the class in which I have initialized the object of my main class.

```
public class MenuControls
{
    MainWindow MainWindowObj = new MainWindow(); //This thing is raising Exception.

    public void SaveAs()
    {

        SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (SFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            String FPath = SFD.FileName;
            StreamWriter SWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Create(FPath));
            SWriter.Write(MainWindowObj.PlayGround.Text);
            SWriter.Dispose();

        }
    }

    public void NewFile()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You haven't saved your file yet ! Do you want to create new file?", "Something", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);   
    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(OFD.FileName));
            MainWindowObj.PlayGround.Text = SReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

My main class code. where I have initialized the Object of my **MenuConrols** class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public RichTextBox GetBox()
    {
        return PlayGround;
    }
    MenuControls Menu = new MenuControls();
    TextEditor_Preferences Prefrences = new TextEditor_Preferences();

    public int SaveStatus = 0;
    TextEditor_Preferences PreferencesForm = new TextEditor_Preferences();
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void MainMenuFile_SaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.SaveAs();
        SaveStatus = 1;
    }

    private void MainMenuFile_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveStatus == 0 && PlayGround.Text.Contains("  "))
        {
            Menu.NewFile();
        } else
        {
            PlayGround.Text = "";
        }

    }

    private void MainMenuFile_Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.OpenFile();
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "N")
        {
            if (SaveStatus == 0 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PlayGround.Text))
            {
                DialogResult DResult = MessageBox.Show("You haven't saved your file yet ! Do you want to create new file?", "Something", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (DResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    PlayGround.Text = "";
                } else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                PlayGround.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "O")
        {
            Menu.OpenFile();
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "S")
        {
            Menu.SaveAs();
            SaveStatus = 1;
        }
    }
    private void MainMenuEdit_Preferences_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PreferencesForm.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

Please suggest me a solution. **If I'm missing something or the question is not asked properly, please let me know explicitly.**
Thanks.

Comment: You have a recursive method call somewhere. Check the stack trace and you'll find it quickly.

Comment: Every Instance of MainWindow creates an instance of MenuControls. And every instance of MenuControls created an instance of MainWindow. -> Endless recursion

Comment: @dymanoid StackOverflowExceptions don't usually include the stack trace with managed debugging.

Comment: How to stop this?

Comment: @ZaryabWaseem stop instantiating the MainWindow in the MenuControls constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because, you have a never ending code getting executed, you are instantiating an instance of `MainWindow` in `MenuControls` class:

```
public class MenuControls
{
    MainWindow MainWindowObj = new MainWindow(); // note this
```

and in `MainWindow` class, you have another field `MenuControls` which is getting instatiated, so when you create `MainWindow` instance, it instatntiates the `MenuControls` field, which again goes to insitialze the `MainWindow` field it has, and it keeps on doing that, hence resulting in stackoverflow exception.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public RichTextBox GetBox()
    {
        return PlayGround;
    }
    MenuControls Menu = new MenuControls(); // note this
```

You need to remove either `MainWindow` field from `MenuControls` class or vice versa, What i see is that you don't need `MainWindow` field in the `MenuControl` class, remove it from there.

Comment: I have a rich text box that I need to use in MenuControls that why I have done this.

Comment: you can pass the richtextbox object as parameter to the contrcutor or some method where you need it in the MenuControls class

Comment: it is not that much clear from the code you have shown, what you are trying to do

Comment: In my MainWindow I have a RichtextBox called PlayGround. In my MenuControl class I have methods like saving, opening and renewing the file. That's why I made the constructor of my MainWindow in my MenuControls to access the PlayGround.

Comment: you can create a `string` field in your ``MenuControls`` class and pass the ``RichTextBox`` in your case ``PlayGround`` control ``Text`` to the method in the ``MenuControls`` class constructor or in the method as parameter

Comment: Thank you for the solution.